# Codeigniter convert data before the view

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a table user with save data like gender, marry status. Im using char(1) to store value to database.Example m for man.
Now I want to convert m to Man before print it to the view.

```
  <?php
            //Gender

            if($query->gender=='m')
            {
                $gender='Man';

            }else if($query->gender=='g')
            {
                 $gender='Gay';
            }else if($query->gender=='l')
            {
                 $gender='Less';
            }else if($query->gender=='w')
            {
                 $gender='Woman';
            }else
            {
                 $gender='No data';
            }
            // End gender
              //Status

            if($query->status=='s')
            {
                $status='Singel';

            }else if($query->status=='m')
            {
                 $status='Married';
            }else if($query->status=='d')
            {
                 $status='Divorced';
            }else
            {
                 $status='No data';
            }
            // End gender


            ?>
```

My question is is there any way to do this kind of things.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? You are already doing conversion. What help do you need?

Comment: You already doing this correct, but you have so many if's, yo can convert it to switch case.
But you are asking for another thing, that how to avoid this code. And get data directly from database.

Comment: My conversion code very long.  So the view look mess up. I'm looking for a solution to make clean code.

Comment: @VuongTran Please use switch case in your code so your code will be clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I found.

```
 $array_gender=array("m"=>"Man","g"=>"Gay","l"=>"Less","w"=>"Woman",""=>"No data");
    echo $array_gender[$query->gender];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL query to replace the single char with full text. I am giving a sample code, replace with your actual code. My code is not for an exact solution but can give you an idea how you can resolve your issue.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name,
              case gender
                 when 'm' then 'Male'
                 when 'f' then 'Female'
              end as gender,
              case gender
                 when 'S' then 'Singel'
                 when 'M' then 'Married'
              end as status 
       FROM user";
$qry = $this->db->query($sql);

then your code....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
                //Gender
                switch ($query->gender) {
                    case 'm':
                        $gender='Man';
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                        $gender='Gay';
                        break;
                    case 'l':
                        $gender='Less';
                        break;
                    case 'w':
                        $gender='Woman';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $gender='No data';
                        break;

                }

                //Status
                switch ($query->status) {
                   case 'S':
                        $status='Singel';
                        break;
                    case 'm':
                        $status='Married';
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        $status='Divorced';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $gender='No data';
                        break;
                }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create three different tables :

`1) Customers (custId, name, age, mobile, genderId[FK], statusId[FK])
2) Gender (genderId, genderText)
3) MaritalStatus (statusId, statusText)`

You can store `statusId` and `genderId` to `customers` table.

Query :

```
$this->db->select("C.custId, C.name, C.age, C.mobile, C.genderId, G.genderText, C.statusId, S.statusText");
$this->db->from("Customers as C");
$this->db->join("Gender as G", "C.genderId = G.genderId");
$this->db->join("MaritalStatus as S", "C.statusId = S.statusId");
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

You got record like this :

`["1", "John Doe", "65", "1234567890", "1", "Male", "2", "Married"]`

Comment: yes it look cleaner for the code. But is it OK to create a table just have 2 rows. 1=male, 2=female. Look funny to me.

Comment: Yes, it looks funny, but its better to give maximum things configurable. Also when it comes to multilingual thing, you can manage your translations in database by giving language keys.